# Image width not expanding on lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a light box to pop up an image when ever you click on it and this is my solution so far:

```
<section>
    <h3>Two Individual Images</h3>
    <div>
        <a style="width:100; height:100;" class="example-image-link" href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfqA9FYaMDCm-6KjRIgumjM4F8EHO2qUiqXICnXHPpMc2M0Pyf" data-lightbox="example-2"><img class="example-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfqA9FYaMDCm-6KjRIgumjM4F8EHO2qUiqXICnXHPpMc2M0Pyf" alt="image-1"/></a>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have applied CSS inline element to increase the width and the height

```
style="width:500; height:500;"
```

Here is plunk I have made

http://plnkr.co/edit/ryX4px00cGvqZ0lszvBO?p=preview

Please why is the image not expanding when clicked.

Comment: Your plnkr has a 404 for the lightbox.. so atm there is no lightbox plugin included

Comment: Its working very well on my browser and on localhost.

Comment: Then please update your plnkr or use jsfiddle instead

Comment: I don't understand why the down vote?

Comment: Why isn't which image expanding? Why should something expand when it is clicked?

Comment: Because I want an image with a reasonable size and width on the lightboxt! Are you trying to say is not achievable? Anything is possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the wrong CSS and JS files. In your plunk they should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.css">
...
<script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, your image does not "expand" because it is exactly the same as your thumbnail. In the `href` you should be linking to a larger image, otherwise it won't "expand".

**EDIT**

If you want to force the image to resize you could override the lightbox CSS (Not recommended, but hey, you can play around with it). Try adding this to the `<head>` after the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.css">`

```
<style>
.lightbox .lb-image {
  width: 100%!important;
  height: auto!important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: There should be a way out.

Comment: See edit above, you could try with different values instead of `100%` it can be specific pixels e.g. `width: 500px`, but in that case you are limited to all images used in lightbox to be forced resize to that width. Small images will pixelate and it is just not best practice. Play with it though, it will help you understand how the library does what it does and then decide if it is right for your needs.

Comment: Nice logic! I was thinking of switching to ionic pop up. But this approach is cool.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that lightbox is calculating the width and heights in inline. So you cant change them with a css rule just that easy.

You have 2 possibilities:

1.
Use a bigger image. Lightbox will then take care.

2. Use the css tag !important. `width: 900px !important;`I do not prefer that solution.

Comment: Didn't work! I have already had a set width and height for this

Comment: It is working. Give the css !important to the img itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to define how many pixels width and height expanding in inline CSS: -

```
<section>
    <h3>Two Individual Images</h3>
    <div>
<a style="width:100px; height:100px;" class="example-image-link" href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfqA9FYaMDCm-6KjRIgumjM4F8EHO2qUiqXICnXHPpMc2M0Pyf" data-lightbox="example-2"><img class="example-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfqA9FYaMDCm-6KjRIgumjM4F8EHO2qUiqXICnXHPpMc2M0Pyf" alt="image-1"/></a></div><hr />
</section>
```